# Циклический tabindex в div

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tab

Задача такая реализация на angular должна быть в виде реализации контроллера или директивы:

```
<div>
    <input type="text" name="firstInput"/>
    <input type="text" name="secondInput"/>
    <button>Отправить</button>
</div>
```

есть `div` с полями `input[type='text']` необходимо не выходя за пределы `div` пройтись по `input`ам, если оказавшись на последнем кликаем `tab` на клавиатуре, то переходим опять на первый `input`.

Comment: Сделать так можно, вопрос только зачем. Если другие элементы страницы не должны использоваться в этот момент, то их можно просто спрятать. Иначе они должны быть доступны по Tab. Подумайте о людях с ограниченными возможностями, например незрячих. Для них контролы не доступные по Tab становятся просто "невидимыми".

Comment: Дело вот в чем - есть несколько однообразных div с полями. к примеру 10 div. Я беру к примеру один из этих div  и задаю ему в angular свойство редактирования, тогда я хочу работать только с его полями. Поэтому и так задумано - обход только в рамках одного выбранного дива. Это реализация клавиатурного управления, так же управлять можно и мышкой, но там все работает и в порядке.

Comment: @dzhioev, например, модальный диалог - не должно быть возможности из него выйти при помощи tab, а нужно его закрыть, нажав ok или отмена. Т. е. при правильном применении всё хорошо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение нашел такое: 
В div перебираем нужные элементы (input / select / a)

```
var elementTabindex = elementDiv[0].querySelectorAll('input[type="text"], select, a.button');
```

Далее проверяем если текущий tabindex больше или равно индексу последнего элемента, то выставляем фокус на первом элементы из имеющихся в этом div.

var currentIndex = document.activeElement.tabIndex || document.documentElement.tabIndex;

```
if(currentIndex  >= elementTabindex[elementTabindex.length-1].tabIndex){
  event.preventDefault();
  elementTabindex[0].focus();
}else if(currentIndex == -1 || currentIndex == 0){
 //для IE и FF
  event.preventDefault();
  elementTabindex[0].focus();}
```

Comment: А если нажать tab из адресной строки браузера?

Comment: То переходит на первый элемент. Используется ангулар, и модуль hotkeys (https://github.com/chieffancypants/angular-hotkeys) поэтому для конкретного дива задается $scope.editing = true;  сочетанием клавиш , а это приводит к тому , что сам див становиться изолированным от других идентичных.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, найти все активные элементы (как минимум `[tabindex], a[href], object, input, select, button`), сохранить тамошнее значение и прописать `-1`. При закрытии диалога вернуть как было.

Другой вариант, обрабатывать из своего кода нажатие tab и переводить фокус на желаемый элемент. Сразу говорю, что надёжность этого способа под вопросом. И случай, требующий отдельной проверки - это мышкой щёлкнуть адресную строку браузера и там нажать tab - этот случай не попадёт под твой обработчик и вопрос уже чисто в том, на какой элемент страницы попадёт фокус первым.